# Purpose of proxyProvide in Dagger 2 generated code

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, generated-code

I have this Dagger module. I want to understand the generated code so I can verify that my Dagger configuration is optimal.

```java
@Module
public class TypefaceModule {

    @Provides @Singleton @Named("Roboto Light")
    static Typeface provideRobotoLight(AssetManager assets) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    }

}
```

Here's the generated code (Dagger 2.14.1):

```java
public final class TypefaceModule_ProvideRobotoLightFactory implements Factory<Typeface> {
  private final Provider<AssetManager> assetsProvider;

  public TypefaceModule_ProvideRobotoLightFactory(Provider<AssetManager> assetsProvider) {
    this.assetsProvider = assetsProvider;
  }

  @Override
  public Typeface get() {
    return Preconditions.checkNotNull(
        TypefaceModule.provideRobotoLight(assetsProvider.get()),
        "Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method");
  }

  public static TypefaceModule_ProvideRobotoLightFactory create(
      Provider<AssetManager> assetsProvider) {
    return new TypefaceModule_ProvideRobotoLightFactory(assetsProvider);
  }

  public static Typeface proxyProvideRobotoLight(AssetManager assets) {
    return Preconditions.checkNotNull(
        TypefaceModule.provideRobotoLight(assets),
        "Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method");
  }
}
```

There are two functions which do almost the same thing: the instance method `get()`, and the static method `proxyProvideRobotoLight()`.

Why has Dagger generated two versions of this code, which both call the module's `provide()` method statically? Can't one call the other?

(Incidentally, I do realise that I no longer need to bundle fonts in my app assets. That's not the question here.)

Comment: Nice observations and interesting question. Seems like we need someone from dagger team to answer the question.

Comment: It is not really transparent here as method was static, so in both cases (`.get` and `.proxyProvide`) it is called without using module instance, otherwise `get` would use references passed and stored via constructor (including module instance) and `proxyProvide` would expect all required details to be passed as arguments. Suppose there is still room for improvement, i.e. detect and reuse static method in generated code.

Comment: @AivarasPrudnikovas would you care to write that up as an answer, perhaps showing some examples of how they would be called differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: Dagger generates this code ahead-of-time so that in a modularized build, you get better build performance. Because of that, we don't know *which* (or both, or neither) that you will need, so we generate both just in case, and assume that Proguard will be able to strip whatever is unused.

**So what are both actually doing?**

The first (the `get()` method) is invoked when the binding that this factory represents is requested as a `Provider<T>`. That can happen either directly, or if the binding is scoped, or a few other scenarios.

The second case is what we call *inlining*. Suppose you have a `@Provides` method in a module, and you have a method on your `@Component` that returns that type. The most ideal code to generate is something like:

```
@Override
public YourBinding y() {
  return YourModule.yourProvidesMethod();
}
```

The thing is, that provides method may not be accessible from the same package as your component, so we generate this "proxy" method which gives Dagger the right accessibility. It also makes accessible all of the parameters to that method, erasing them to `Object` if necessary. And if they do get erased (think of this like generic type erasure), we need to then insert the casts to the correct types *inside* the proxy method.

The `Provider.get()` implementation doesn't need that, because there, all of the types should are accessible by the code that invokes it.

So to sum up - we want to generate both versions, hopefully you should only use one, and Proguard should clean up the other.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So the only purpose of these `provideProxy` methods is to get access if the module is in another package?

Comment: Also, are `Provider`s not used by Dagger internally if we neither add scope annotations nor request a `Provider` directly?

Comment: They're also used if any of the parameters need to be null checked. In many cases they'll be used.

Comment: Providers are also use if the binding is requested by another type for which a Provider is needed (for the reasons you mentioned). So if you have A -> B -> C, an A is scoped, B _and_ C will have Provider instances

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In earlier versions of Dagger, everything was returned from `Provider<>`s, whereas in newer versions most of the calls have been inlined to make the code more efficient. Is that correct? In a very simple scenario without scope I have created, no `_Factory` is ever instantiated as a `Provider<>`

Comment: Also, do you have a quick explanation for why scope requires a Provider wrapper? Couldn't the object instantiation still be inlined without a Provider?